# using data from two tables in mysql by using php5

Tags: mysql

i want to get data from a table and use in the form's field and along with some new fields data i want to save all fields data in a new table,,'
then what i have to do ,
thanxs in advance !!

Comment: Check  this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on how to write and ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

> Get the require data from the table, Then create the form with those needed values.
>
> Then do the validation  . Once the validation is completed , put these new data's in your new table.